# What free tool can I use to limit network speed on LAN to test my application?

Tags: networking, lan

I need to test my C# application that uses WCF for slow network speeds on Windows 7.

Are there any free tools out their that can reduce my network speed?

Comment: @Code Gray: I guess in addition to what you have suggested, he has to browse some crack and serial sites and download from there to get faster effect :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://bandwidthcontroller.com/trafficShaperXp.html

A [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=windows+bandwidth+limiter) will give you some more ...

--[EDIT---

This runs on Win7 x64

http://www.softperfect.com/products/bandwidth/

This is not free, but trial version available. Has a lite version also.

Comment: NetBalancer is great tool and works for me http://www.seriousbit.com/netbalancer/

Comment: @Rohit: So, if you already have an app to do this job, then what is the point posting the question here?

Comment: I got it from your keywords for google search. This was to help others.

Comment: @SarwarErfan Maybe because other people might have that question too?

Answer (score 9):

[Clumsy](http://jagt.github.io/clumsy/index.html) does a pretty good job as well.

Comment: Clumsy is just great, much easier than other options.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a linux machine (on a cheap Atom is fine) and use CBQ .. more details at http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/Bandwidth-Limiting-HOWTO.html#CBQ

Comment: Its a C# application. So, why are you suggesting Linux tool?